# Best practices for imports for installed package

Tags: python, import, distutils

Imagine I have a package "foolibrary" that is installed via setup.py, and I'm the primary developer.  Which is the preferred means of calling imports inside the package?  Imagine foolibrary has two modules (a.py, b.py) and I need to access them in c.py:

- foolibrary

  - a.py
  - b.py
  - c.py

In c.py, what is the preferred way to import these and why?

```
from a import blah
```

vs

```
from foolibrary.a import blah
```

vs

```
from .a import blah
```

I've seen all three and generally use the `foolibrary.a import` style, but mostly out of habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative import syntax, `from .a import blah`, is **the** modern way to do things.  See PEP 328, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/ , as to why it's superior to the alternatives.  (Though admittedly PEP 8 prefers absolute exports, it also allows within-package relative imports as an acceptable alternative).

Personally, BTW, I always ever import only **modules**, not "stuff" (functions, classes, whatever) from inside a module.

But, this is a style constraint that is far from universal (it **is**, however, part of https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html -- and having been at Google 10 years now and helped shape parts of its Python practices and style, I'm understandably biased in favor of that style:-).

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I appreciate that someone of your caliber would take the time to answer my lowly question.  Yes, I also am trying to be more devoted to importing only modules, and it's amazing how arduous it tends to feel considering how small an effort it really takes.   I'm going to apply to Google Pittsburgh soon, and will be sure to start following this style closely.  Thank you for sharing.